# C++ template function to delete and reset pointers

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, delete-operator

I just ran into a minor problem regarding pointers.
As I wanted to have a quick and easy way to do this task in a single line:

```
...
delete pointer;
pointer = 0;
...
```

I just quickly set up a simple header file with a template method that accepts any type of pointer. It looks like this:

```
#ifndef P_DELETE_H
#define P_DELETE_H

template <typename T>
void pDelete(T* pointer) {
  if (pointer) {
    delete pointer;
    pointer = 0;
  }
}

#endif
```

However, the results don't meet my expectations of the object beeing deleted and the pointer beeing reset. Instead, it seems that only the object was deleted, but setting it to zero had no effect (which is what I'd need). If somebody here could lighten me up a little and explain this behavior, I'd apreceate that much!

**UPDATE:**

As the answers explain, using std::unique_ptr and std::shared_ptr is the safer way to go than nullifying this pointers.

But if you really need to go such way as I requested, the following code will do the trick:

```
template <typename T>
inline void pDelete(T*& pointer) {
  if (pointer) {
    delete pointer;
    pointer = 0;
  }
}
```

However, this is generally unsafe to use, even though it correctly deletes and nullifies the pointer on all instances (quick test revealed this).

Thanks to everyone for the informative answers!

Comment: Function arguments are local to the function scope. This includes pointers. You'd have to use a pointer reference or pointer pointer to affect the value outside the function. (Or stop using raw pointers and you won't have a need for this whole thing.)

Comment: You need a reference parameter: `void pDelete(T*& pointer)`

Comment: You do know about *references* and how to pass arguments *by reference*?

Comment: Using a smart pointer library (like `std::unique_ptr`) eliminates the need to write this sort of code altogether.

Comment: I second the smart pointer approach.  This approach is error prone.  For instance if you pass a pointer that was allocated with `new[]` you would have undefined behavior.

Comment: The need for coding hacks like this are often the result of bad design.

Comment: Note that this approach can give a false sense of security: `int* ip = new int; int* ip1 = ip; pDelete(ip); if (ip1) std::count << *ip1 << '\n';` Despite the test, that last line dereferences a dangling pointer.

Comment: I'm aware of smart pointers and their advantages, but in some cases I can't use them/they are impractible/pointless. Regarding QT libraries it is nonsense to keep everything in shared_ptr when the lib itself could do some weird unexpected stuff.

Comment: @Migsi Actually a `unqiue_ptr` should be the default go to.  The only overhead is the delete call and you need to do that regardless so you might as well take advantage of RAII.

Comment: Even when standard smart pointers are not appropriate (very rare), you should still be using some form of RAII - which means that your `delete`s would all be in destructors, which would mean that _the pointers become inaccessible_ after the delete - which means you _never need to reset them_.

Comment: @NathanOliver: I'd argue, that more there's an even more important aspect to smart pointers than the ability to use the RAII idiom: Source code locality between resource acquisition and its appropriate deleter.

Comment: @Migsi: What weird unexpected stuff does Qt do? You either allocate an object with a parent - in that case you never have to call delete on it. Or you allocate it without parent and then you can safely use a smart pointer.

Comment: @IInspectable That's a good point.  You only want it to live in the needed scope.  No need to hang on to things that are no longer needed.

Answer (score 6):

The solution you're looking for is:

```
delete pointer;
pointer = nullptr;
```

Yeah, just write that code in-line. There's really no reason to introduce another function template somewhere that people will have to look up to figure out what it actually does, just to save one line of code.

The above is perfectly readable and easy to understand.

Comment: However, you forget to mention that above is pretty moot. if there would be any benefit in nulling out pointers after delete, they would be nulled automatically.

Comment: @SergeyA Of course there's benefit. It's just typically you don't need that benefit, which is why they aren't nulled automatically.

Comment: 'typically you do not need the benefit' - exactly.

Comment: In my case I need this benefit to handle some things afterwards. Checking if a certain pointer was cleared is only possible if it is set to nullptr, any other value would assume it is still set. Anyways having a template doing this prevents from typos in long destructors, where lots of pointers should be cleared.

Comment: @Migsi It sounds like you need a code refactor.  A lot of manual pointer management is typically a sign of bad design unless you are writing your own basic container type.

Comment: @Migsi, this is exactly what I have said in my comment. You need to refactor your code, what you are trying to do is very error prone, and most likely, wrong.

Comment: @Migsi: The way to prevent bugs, that are the result of two-line raw pointer delete-and-reset statements is not, to have a function template do it in one line. The only solution that can reliably prevent this class of error is to not have any pointers, that need to be manually cleaned up. Smart pointers are a common solution.

Answer (score 1):

The whole thing you are trying to do is moot. Have you thought about the reason why this is not happening automatically? Why runtime doesn't nullify the pointer after deletion? Because C++ standard committee wasn't smart enough?

No. Because it does you no good most of the time. Yes, you nullify this instance of the pointer - but the whole reason why you had the pointer to begin with is likely that this pointer is living somewhere else well! (there are exceptions to this, of course). As a result, all your nullifying is saving you from is incorrect access on this instance of the pointer - but not on any other instance. In essence, it gives you false feeling of safety.

Rather than engaging in false feeling of safety, adopt usage of automatic pointers - `std::unique_ptr` should be first choice, and if it doesn't suffice, `std::shared_ptr` - but make sure you really need it!

Comment: If you can explain me how to use shared_ptr best with QT I'd switch over using them right now.
I'm aware using those is way safer and cleaner, but where I need to involve qt functions it seems pointless to me.

Comment: @Migsi, I do not know much about Qt, but as far as I understand, Qt has it's own smart pointer facility?

Comment: @Migsi If you're invoking `delete` directly when dealing with QT objects, there's really no reason not to presume that the same patterns normally used with `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` would not apply in your situation.

Comment: @Xirema So you're saying I can handle QT object pointers just like custom ones and don't need to worry when I give the raw pointer as a parameter to a QT function? I'd be happy if that's right!

Answer (score 1):

Stop using raw pointers to denote ownership. If you take ownership of an object through a pointer, it should go into a `std::unique_ptr`.

Your situation is then `pointer.reset()`.

If you want to let other code observe the object owned by you, without a transfer of ownership, you can use `pointer.get()` to get a non-owning pointer. You can also use `*pointer` to get a reference.

If you have to pass that ownership through an interface that uses raw pointers (I'm looking at you, Qt), use `pointer.release()`.

Comment: So I shall ".release()" all pointers going into QT? Also, when do I even have to care about pointers I give into or get from QT? The documentation often leaves this quite unclear...

Comment: Well if you were unclear before with the raw pointers, you were either leaking or double deleting. Nothing has changed in that respect. Qt generally only transfers ownership via pointers in the "Parent/Child" relationship mutators